# How to validate is PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager is applied on jersey client

Tags: java, jersey, httpclient, jersey-client

Below is the code snippet I am using for jersey client connection pooling.

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, defaultConnectTimeout);
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, defaultReadTimeout);
        
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(50);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, cm);

clientConfig.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
```

How can I validate that my client is using connection pooling? Is **poolStats.getAvailable()** count is valid way of making sure ? In my case this available count is 1 when I tested client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the count can be 1, but to confirm you can try following steps.

1. You can first add a thread that keep running in background and prints the existing state of poolstats at some interval, lets say every 60 sec. You can use below logic. Ensure you are referring to same PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager object instance in below logic code running as a part of background thread.
2. Then, try calling the logic which internally makes call to external service using the mentioned jersey client in continuation (may be in for loop)
3. You should see different logs (in your thread logic) getting printed which would confirm that the jersey client is actually using the pooled configuration.

Logic:

```
PoolStats poolStats = cm.getTotalStats();
        Set<HttpRoute> routes = cm.getRoutes();
        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(routes)) {
            for (HttpRoute route : routes) {
                PoolStats routeStats = poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getStats(route);
                int routeAvailable = routeStats.getAvailable();
                int routeLeased = routeStats.getLeased();
                int routeIdle = (routeAvailable - routeLeased);
                log.info("Pool Stats for Route - Host = {}, Available = {} , Leased = {}, Idle = {}, Pending = {}, Max = {} " ,
                        route.getTargetHost(), routeAvailable, routeLeased, routeIdle, poolStats.getPending(), poolStats.getMax());
            }
        }

        int available = poolStats.getAvailable();
        int leased = poolStats.getLeased();
        int idle = (available - leased);
        log.info("Pool Stats - Available = {} , Leased = {}, Idle = {}, Pending = {}, Max = {} " ,
                available, leased, idle, poolStats.getPending(), poolStats.getMax());
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I followed the similar way and able to test it. Below is the article that I followed.
https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management